# R shiny: Create reactively drop down choices or autocompletion with multiple data sets

Tags: r, autocomplete, shiny, user-input, reactive

I would like to provide reactively drop down choices (autocomplete suggestions) to the user depending on the input he provides. User input and autocomplete suggestions should be in the same widget.

The problem is, that I have a large data set (1 million rows+) from which the user should be able to choose names from. Since preloading this large data set would slow down the app, I would like to work with multiple splitted data sets, which I load depending on first letter of the user input.

The goal is to provide something like a textInput widget where the user is able to start typing a name. Depending on the first letter of this user input, I would like to present suggestions to the user from which he should be able to choose from.

Unfortunately this is not possible with:

- textInput (lacks of drop down with suggestions)
- selectInput / selectizeInput / select2Input (lacks of ability to work with non-pre loaded data)

Here are my failed trails with different input widgets to get this to work.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinysky)

#ui
ui <- fluidPage(

  #Text Input
  textInput(inputId = "txtInput", label = "Text Input", value = NULL),

  #Select Input
  selectInput(inputId = "selectInput", label = "Select Input", choices = NULL),

  #Selectize Input
  selectizeInput(inputId = "selectizeInput", label = "Selectize Input", choices = NULL),

  #Select2Input from shinysky
  select2Input(inputId = "select2Input", label = "Select2 Input", choices = NULL)
)

#server
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #Create reactive values
  rv <- reactiveValues()

  #Function for loading specific data set
  f.populate.values <- function(start.letter) {

    data.set <- c()

    if(start.letter == "a") {

      #Example toy list
      data.set <- c("aaa", "abc", "adb", "adf") 
    }

    if(start.letter == "b") {

      #Example toy list
      data.set <- c("baa", "bbc", "bdb", "bdf") 
    }
    return(data.set)
  }

  #Failed trials to update / generate a dropdown with the loaded data set from "f.populate.values"
  observeEvent(input$txtInput, {

    #Store loaded data depending on first typed character
    rv$names <- f.populate.values(substring(input$txtInput, 1, 1))

    #Trials to update suggestions in widgets
    updateTextInput(inputId = "txtInput", value = rv$names, session = session)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "selectInput", choices = rv$names, session = session)
    updateSelectizeInput(inputId = "selectizeInput", choices = rv$names, session = session)
    updateSelect2Input(inputId = "select2Input", choices = rv$names, label = "Select 2 Input", session = session)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```